# Derive E[Y|X] when the joint probability is given

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, expected-value, density-function, conditional-expectation

Now, consider joint density of $X, Y$ :
$$
f_{X, Y}(x, y)=\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\frac{1}{\pi} ; X^2+Y^2<1 \\
0 ; \text { Otherwise }
\end{array}\right.
$$
Derive $E(Y \mid X)$.

I know how to calculate E(Y), but how do you calculate the conditional expectation? please help

Comment: Find the conditional density.

Comment: Hi. Please add [tag:self-study] tag. Problems like these warrant minimal research efforts. As @StubbornAtom indicated, proceed with this and update your post if you stumble.

Comment: Questions of this type can be answered either by (i) applying the analytic formulas for conditional densities and expectation from statistical theory or (ii) geometrically from the shape of the joint density. In this case the answer is immediately obvious from the geometry if you know how to think about it.